# Logistic Modeling with Probability

Tags: regression, logistic, python, scikit-learn

For each predicted value in a logistic model, is there any way of also obtaining a "probability score"? I'm using Python's SKLearn library to create a logistic regression model that either predicts either 1 or 0 and I would like to have another column indicating how "sure" the model is of the particular outcome. The closest that I've come is using a Linear Regression Model instead, which comes out with a number between 0 and 1. Not sure whether this is a good "probability" to use. Also, there are outcomes outside the range. Is there any way to do this or a better method for this type of analysis?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a predict_proba method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with SKLearn, but a logistic regression model per se actually provides a probability of class membership. The classification comes at a later stage when you specify a probability cutoff (typically 1/2, but that can be adjusted if, for example, different misclassification errors have different costs). I would recommend looking into the SKLearn documentation for how to get the probability values from the program.

Comment: It just doesn't seem like the OP'er is looking at it the right way. I have never used SKLearn, but a quick search produced [this Jupyter Notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/justmarkham/6d5c061ca5aee67c4316471f8c2ae976) example with a clear probability of log odds ratio (I don't know).

Comment: @ Antoni Parellada, it looks like I just had to use predict_proba. Thanks!